# What does this error mean when trying to use an AppRole from Vault on an Ingress deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, vault

## Context

We were trying to fix an inconsistency between Terraform and our cloud provider because a database was deleted through the cloud's UI console and the changes were not properly imported into Terraform.

For reasons we preferred to not do `terraform import` and proceeded to change the state file to remove all references to that database hoping that would allow us to run things like `plan`, and it did work, but we came across other issues...

Oh, I should add that we run things like Helm through Terraform to set up our Kubernetes infra as well.

## The problem

Now Terraform makes a plan to remove a Google Container Node Pool (desired outcome) and to update a Kubernetes resource of kind Ingress. The latter change is not really intended, although it could be because there's a Terraform module dependency between the module that sets up all the cluster (including node pools) and the module that sets up Ingress.

Now the issue comes from updating that Ingress. Here's the plan:

```
# Terraform will read AppRole from Vault

data "vault_approle_auth_backend_role_id" "role"  {
  - backend   = "approle" -> null
  ~ id        = "auth/approle/role/nginx-ingress/role-id" -> (known after apply)
  ~ role_id   = "<some UUID>" -> (known after apply)
    role_name = "nginx-ingress"
}

# Now this is the resource that makes everything blow up

resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" {
    atomic                     = false
    chart                      = ".terraform/modules/nginx-ingress/terraform/../helm"
    ...

    ...
  - set_sensitive {
      - name  = "appRole.roleId" -> null
      - value = (sensitive value)
    }

  + set_sensitive {
      + name  = "appRole.roleId"
      + value = (sensitive value)
    }

  - set_sensitive {
      - name  = "appRole.secretId" -> null
      - value = (sensitive value)
    }

  + set_sensitive {
      + name  = "appRole.secretId"
      + value = (sensitive value)
    }
}
```

And here's the error message we get:

```
When expanding the plan for module.nginx-ingress.helm_release.nginx-ingress to
include new values learned so far during apply, provider
"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm" produced an invalid new value for
.set_sensitive: planned set element
cty.ObjectVal(map[string]cty.Value{"name":cty.StringVal("appRole.secretId"),
"type":cty.NullVal(cty.String),
"value":cty.StringVal("<some other UUID>")}) does not
correlate with any element in actual.

This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own
issue tracker.
```

## What we tried

- We thought that maybe the AppRole's secretId had rotated or changed, so we took the secretId from the State of another environment that uses the same AppRole from the same Vault and set it in our modified state file. That didn't work.

Comment: "proceeded to change the state file to remove all references to that database" root cause right there. Are the reasons to not `terraform state mv` or `terraform state rm/terraform import` that compelling?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Overly simplistic pragmatism: the cost of setting up terraform locally for importing seemed higher than the cost of trying to change the state. We admittedly miss our DevOps team, who configured everything to run on jenkins.

Comment: Ok, and you cannot modify the `Jenkinsfile` in source or embedded in the job to execute the `terraform import` within a one-off pipeline to modify the state? I am speculating based on estimates of permissions, interfacing, and state configuration.

Comment: Approaching this instead from the Vault perspective instead of Jenkins: can you regenerate the AppRole authentication data in Terraform, and not attempt to verify idempotence by manipulating the state? That could maybe also fix this. I would also guess that this issue cannot be rectified through a change in Helm usage with the Helm provider.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I think running the `import` from Jenkins sounds like a good bet. We considered regenerating the AppRole, but it's shared between other cluster instances' Ingresses and we were afraid of affecting something else. I guess that if we take that path, we should specify a unique approle name.